# How to form a triplet of connected components to form an undirected graph?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, networkx

I want to create an undirected graph of size 3 from a given dataset(.tsv file).
I have done it in R, but i can't do it in python, and my guide insisted to do it in python since it is a more trending language.
Little bit of help will be highly appreciated.

Tried to use this code, which i found here in stackoverflow, but didn't work at all.
The code:

```py
    import networkx as nx
    import pandas as pd
    from itertools import chain

    adj_matrix = [
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    ]

    df = pd.DataFrame(adj_matrix)

    G = nx.from_pandas_adjacency(df)

    # filter components of size 3
    triplets = [c for c in nx.connected_components(G) if len(c) == 3]
```

My Code so far

```py
    a_col=length(adj[1,])
    a_row=length(adj[,1])

    trip=NULL  #NULL matrix to store triplet values

    for(i in 1:a_row)
    {
      for(j in 1:a_col)
      {
        if(adj[i,j]==1)
        {
          for(k in (j+1):a_col)
          {
            if(adj[i,k]==1)
           {
            cat("\nTriplets: ",i,j,k)
            trip<-rbind(trip,c(i,j,k))
           }
        }  
        for(l in (i+1):a_row)
        {
          if(adj[l,j]==1)
          {
           cat("\nTriplets: ",i,j,l)
           trip<-rbind(trip,c(i,j,l))
          }
         }
       }
     }
    }
```

The data set i used:

```
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1
0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   1   0
0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

The expected triplets are:

```
3   5   8
3   5   6
3   5   9
4   9   10
4   9   5
```

Comment: Please, clarify your question with an example of what you have (input) and what you want to get (output). Thanks.

Comment: I have already given the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd

# 1. Transform your data to python list of lists:
data = [
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1],
    [0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0],
    [0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]
]

# 2. Create Pandas dataframe from the data
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# 3. Create graph from the adjacency matrix
G = nx.from_pandas_adjacency(df)

# 4. Print all connected components
for c in nx.connected_components(G):
    print(c)

# END
```

will print:

```
{0}
{1}
{2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9}
{6}
```

Let's draw this graph:

`nx.draw(G)`

[image]

Here is how you can process graphs with networkx. Your graph has no connected components with length=3 and no triages so I don't know what you expect to get. But if you want to find various types of triangles, you can run this function:

`nx.triangles(G)`

Comment: I am getting this error:

`File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\networkx\drawing\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .nx_pylab import *
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\networkx\drawing\nx_pylab.py", line 42
    [docs]def draw(G, pos=None, ax=None, hold=None, **kwds):
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax `

Comment: Maybe you copied more that needed (`will print:`, for example)? Note that I am mixing code and text in my answer (there are two different fonts).

Comment: No,i did not copy that. I only copied till `print(c)`

Comment: Remove `nx.draw(G)`, and try to re-run script. Looks like you have a different version of networkx.

Comment: @vurmux The code is working now. But when i tried to find the triplet in R,i got the result. But surprisingly,its not coming in python. I have even uploaded my R code and the output i got with it.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the same data in R and Python? Look at graph from `nx.draw()`, there are no triplets or 3-nodes connected components.